# Matrix 3d transform for obtaining trapezoid?

Tags: css, animation, jquery-animate, transform

I try to simulate a turn to back effect, as two doors open to back simultaneously. I tried different matrix generators to obtain that trapezoid needed but i didn't  have any luck. I know i have to animate an rotateY from 0 to 180 degrees and to keep my transform origin but that trapezoid kills me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `perspective`?

### [***demo***](http://dabblet.com/gist/4611011)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='doors'>
    <div class='door'></div><div class='door'></div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.doors { perspective: 35em; }
.door {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%; height: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
}
.doors:hover .door:first-child {
    transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
.doors:hover .door:last-child {
    transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
    transform: rotateY(-60deg);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't give a trapezoid

Comment: The code here does. But dizzy me forgot to save that last version of the demo. Fixed now. Tested and works in Chrome, Firefox, IE10, Safari (Opera does not support 3D transforms).

Comment: Very interesting. It seems the key to getting this to work is to assign a perspective to the parent of the transformed div...