# Stacking order (z-index) when using transform

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

At the the fiddle below I have a right nav which has a submenu, the submenu should appear as the user enters text in the search field. ATM. I had to place the search box outside of the navbar (`.link-list`) since the element containing the submenu appears over it thus making it impossible to type in. In the final solution the search field is supposed to be within the `.link-list`.

The submenu folds out if you hover it but I want it to be invisible until the user enters anything in the search field. It should close if the search field is cleared or if a link with `.close-sub` is clicked.

What do I need to do to achieve this, have experimented with `z-index`, code order, fixed and absolute positions but no success.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1yxk8w6p/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="search" id="srch"></input>
<div class='link-list'>
<h1>Navbar</h1>
<div class="lnk">
    <a href="#">monkey</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">bizniz</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">monkey</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">bizniz</a>
</div>
<div class='sub'>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Integer molestie lorem at massa</li>
    <li>Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet</li>
    <li>Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
      <ul>
        <li>Phasellus iaculis neque</li>
        <li>Purus sodales ultricies</li>
        <li>Vestibulum laoreet porttitor sem</li>
        <li>Ac tristique libero volutpat at</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Faucibus porta lacus fringilla vel</li>
    <li>Aenean sit amet erat nunc</li>
    <li>Eget porttitor lorem</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.link-list {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 16em;
  perspective: 180em;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sub {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: dimgrey;
  transition: .6s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 16em;
  overflow: auto;
  transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.link-list:hover .sub {
  transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  position: fixed;
  right: 16em;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
  background: salmon;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: your html code in `fiddle` and `stackoverflow` are different. Am i missing something...?

Comment: the only difference I notice is the indentation, I'll add the CSS here as well in case that's of any help.

Comment: the fiddle points to question by [Matrix 3d transform for obtaining trapezoid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480341/matrix-3d-transform-for-obtaining-trapezoid) @Dan Ovidiu Boncut. it has commented URL to the Question

Comment: when I clicked that link in chrome I got the right page, tried it in firefox, got the one you got. Weirdness. Anyway, its updated now.

Comment: realy....!!! thats weired man.... it should be reported to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/1yxk8w6p/).. well let me look at it now to see what you got...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/erupvto6/16/)?

```js
$('.js-search').on(
    'propertychange change keyup input paste',
    function() {
        var $naviSub = $('.js-navi-sub');
        var isShown = $naviSub.data('is-shown');

        if (isShown !== Boolean($(this).val())) {
            $naviSub.data('is-shown', !isShown)
                    .toggleClass('navi__sub_shown');
        }
    }
);

$('.js-close').on('click', function() {
    var $naviSub = $('.js-navi-sub');

    $naviSub.data('is-shown', false)
            .removeClass('navi__sub_shown');
});
```

```css
.navi {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 16em;
    -webkit-perspective: 180em;
    perspective: 180em;
    background: pink;
}

    .navi__main {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .navi__header {
        background: salmon;
    }

    .navi__sub {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: dimgrey;
        top: 0;
        right: 16em;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

        .navi__sub_shown {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }

    .navi__close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: gray;
    }

        .navi__close:hover {
            color: red;
        }

    .navi__list {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navi">
    <div class="navi__main">
        <h1 class="navi__header">Navbar</h1>
        <input type="search" id="srch" class="js-search"/>
        <div class="lnk">
            <a href="#">monkey</a>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">bizniz</a>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">monkey</a>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">bizniz</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navi__sub js-navi-sub">
        <span class="navi__close js-close">×</span>
        <ul class="navi__list">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
            <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
            <li>Integer molestie lorem at massa</li>
            <li>Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet</li>
            <li>Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
                <ul>
                    <li>Phasellus iaculis neque</li>
                    <li>Purus sodales ultricies</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum laoreet porttitor sem</li>
                    <li>Ac tristique libero volutpat at</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Faucibus porta lacus fringilla vel</li>
            <li>Aenean sit amet erat nunc</li>
            <li>Eget porttitor lorem</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```