# How to change the border to uploaded image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, image-upload

```js
function readURL(event){
   var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   $('#trapezoid').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePath + ')');
  }
```

```css
#clock{
     background-image:url('');
     background-size:cover;
     background-position: center;
     height: 250px; width: 250px;
     border: 1px solid #bbb;
   }
      
      #trapezoid {
 border-bottom: 30px solid red;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
 height: 80px;
 width:35px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(93deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(93deg);
  -o-transform: rotate6(93deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(93deg);
  transform: rotate(93deg);
  float="left";
  display="inline-block"
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" onchange="readURL(event)" /><br/><br/> 
  <div id="trapezoid">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have this snippet, What I want is when any user uploads any photo then red colored part should get replaced by the uploaded photo instead of whole area.

Please help me how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `perspective`, `transform`, `transform-origin`, as demonstrated by @Ana at [Matrix 3d transform for obtaining trapezoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480341/matrix-3d-transform-for-obtaining-trapezoid)

```js
function readURL(event) {
  var getImagePath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $("#trapezoid").css("background", "url(" + getImagePath + ")")
}
```

```css
.doors {
  margin: 7em auto;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  perspective: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
}

#trapezoid {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.doors #trapezoid {
  transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  transform: rotateY(93deg);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" onchange="readURL(event)" /><br/><br/>
  <div class="doors">
    <div id="trapezoid">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Working like a champ. Thanks buddy. @guest271314

Comment: Can you help me little bit more, how can I create exactly mirror image of same, so that after upload both first trapezoid and mirror image get reflected. @guest271314

Comment: could draw the images to `<canvas>`, preserving trapezoid dimensions, then call `.toBlob()` or `.toDataURL()` to get the rendered image. See original post by @Ana for "mirror" image, or open door effect.